# Accessing Band Set Information from Bing or Google maps?

Tags: google, multi-band

i would like to use Bing or Google hybrid Layers and perform spectral analysis on it. Ideally, I would access seperate Band Set Information as in Landsat or Sentinel data. Is that possible with Bing or Google hybrid Layers at specific locations? Alternatively, can I perform a spectral analysis on images from google hybrid and create multi Band raster from them?

Im a newbie to GIS and only need this application.

Answer (score -1):

Google does sell add-on licenses for NIR data, see https://support.google.com/mapsdata/?hl=en . So whether it's possible depends on how much you want to pay, and you need to be US-based.

Why do you want google/bing imagery and not use sentinel data?

Comment: As far as I understand, google/bing imagery contains arail images not only satelite which provides a much higher spatial resolution at specific places ( as far as i can tell from google/bing Layers imported with OpenLayers plugin). In my case I am trying to detect roads or pathes in rural areas. I've tried this with Landsat/Sentinel2 data but there are much to coarse to detect them reliably (even by eye).